# Where can I get historical ticker change database?

Tags: data, historical-data

There's 30 days worth of data at http://www.otcmarkets.com/marketActivity/symbol-changes - but I'm really looking for the past 10 years, or 5 years if only that is possible. Any dice?

The closest I've come, and this is not really cutting it, is looking up a stock via Yahoo! Finance and seeing "TICKER is no longer valid. It has changed to NEWTICKER".

But that's not helpful; for example in the case of Skye industries, it used to trade as SKYY.  But now SKYY tracks some sort of cloud computing ETF.

Happy to pay for the data.

Comment: Most large data vendors have corporate actions: Bloomberg, Thomson Reuters, CompuStat, etc.

Comment: Still looking for a good answer to this, one example for others to validate: on 2020-10-25 Arlington Asset Investment Corp stopped using **AI** on the NYSE, then on 2020-12-09 C3.AI started using **AI** on the NYSE.

Answer (score 3):

This may or may not help you depending on what resources are available to you.

If you happen to have access to any source of daily data which contains both tickers and SEDOLs (i.e., the London Stock exchange unique identifiers; these are quite commonly used), then you can trivially derive 99% of all ticker changes. When a ticker changes, the SEDOLs typically remain unchanged, so a quick script comparing the ticker-to-SEDOL mapping from day to day should reveal most changes. Once in a blue moon, a SEDOL will change on the same day as the ticker and there's nothing you can do about it, but that almost never happens. I've used this trick many times when exploring new markets for which I don't have ticker change info.

Note: CUSIPs and ISINs don't seem to work very well for this; you really need SEDOLs.

Answer (score 3):

Although is an old question, but here's the [list](https://otce.finra.org/otce/dailyList?viewType=Symbol%2FName%20Changes)

Comment: This source applies only to US OTC stocks.

Answer (score 3):

There is at least one data vendor that I have in my mind right now which can offer you such kind of information. algoseek have a very good product:
[security master file](https://www.algoseek.com/products.html#us_equity_reference_data).

There you can find ticker changes for all securities from 2007. You can check a sample on their website to see how it looks like.

Answer (score -2):

you can download the financial data from sec api where they have the old trading symbol from past.